# Combination of Canvas.TransparentColor and Canvas.Draw with Opacity

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, delphi-xe5, alpha-transparency

i want to draw a bitmap on a canvas with opacity where the bitmap has a transparent color.

- i could create a bitmap with transparent color and draw it to a
- canvas i could create a bitmap and draw it to a canvas with opacity

but i couldn't combine it. if i combine it the opacity is ignored.

here is the code i wrote:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var b1,b2:TBitmap;
begin
  // Example how it opacity works:
  b1 := TBitmap.Create;
  b1.SetSize(20,20);
  b1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  b1.Canvas.Rectangle(0,0,20,20);
  Canvas.Draw(10,10,b1,$ff);  // Works
  Canvas.Draw(40,10,b1,$66);  // Works

  // I need it in combination with TransparentColor:
  b2 := TBitmap.Create;
  // next 3 lines are different from above
  b2.Transparent := true;
  b2.TransparentColor := clFuchsia;
  b2.Canvas.Brush.Color := clFuchsia;
  b2.SetSize(20,20);
  b2.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  b2.Canvas.Ellipse(0,0,20,20);
  Canvas.Draw(10,40,b2,$ff);  // Works (full opacity)
  Canvas.Draw(40,40,b2,$66);  // Ignores the $66 Opacity

  b1.Free;
  b2.Free;
end;
```

produces:
[image]

how could i draw (f.e. a blue circle) with transparent background and just 40% opacity?

i would prefere a solution without direct winapi (like bitblt, ...) if possible.

i tried a few hacks like bitshifting a alpha channel to a TColor value but it didn't work.

here i what i tried:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var b:TBitmap;
begin
  b := TBitmap.Create;
  b.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  b.AlphaFormat := afDefined;

  b.Canvas.Brush.Color := 0 and ($ff shl 32);  // Background Transperency
  b.SetSize(20,20);
  b.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue + (($ff-$66) shl 32);
  b.Canvas.Ellipse(0,0,20,20);
  Canvas.Draw(10,10,b);

  b.Free;
end;
```

produces:
[image]

thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** my system: delphi xe 5 on windows 7 64bit (but using the 32bit compiler)

Comment: In Firemonkey the opacity is a floating point value from 0 to 1, but I suppose you are on VCL.

Comment: @Hans: you are right, i am on vcl. the opacity is a byte value from 0-255.

Comment: Hi linluk, please don't put answers into questions. You may always answer your own questions in the answer section. :)

Comment: ok, i add an answer. thx for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens can be seen in `procedure TBitmap.DrawTransparent` in the unit Graphics.
If the property of the image is set to transparent as show for b2 in your example the Bitmap will be drawn with 
`Graphics.TransparentStretchBlt` which is using `StretchBlt` with differnt masks to draw the image and is not able to use the alpha channel.
A not tranparent Bitmap , your b1, will be draw with 
[AlphaBlend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351(v=vs.85).aspx).

To reach your goal you might use another bitmap b2, set the Alphachannel to 0, paint b2 with opacity $66 on b3, set set the Alphachannel to 255 for every pixel which is clFuchsia in b2 and then paint this bitmap with the desired opacity

[image][image]

```
type
  pRGBQuadArray = ^TRGBQuadArray;
  TRGBQuadArray = ARRAY [0 .. 0] OF TRGBQuad;
  TRefChanel=(rcBlue,rcRed,rcGreen);

procedure SetBitmapAlpha(ABitmap: TBitMap; Alpha: Byte);
var
  pscanLine32: pRGBQuadArray;
  nScanLineCount, nPixelCount : Integer;
begin
  with ABitmap do
  begin
    PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
    HandleType := bmDIB;
    ignorepalette := true;
    alphaformat := afDefined;
    for nScanLineCount := 0 to Height - 1 do
    begin
      pscanLine32 := Scanline[nScanLineCount];
      for nPixelCount := 0 to Width - 1 do
        with pscanLine32[nPixelCount] do
         begin
          rgbReserved := Alpha;
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure AdaptBitmapAlpha(ABitmap,TranspBitmap:TBitmap);
var
  pscanLine32,pscanLine32_2: pRGBQuadArray;
  nScanLineCount, nPixelCount : Integer;
begin
  with ABitmap do
  begin
    PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
    HandleType := bmDIB;
    ignorepalette := true;
    alphaformat := afDefined;
    for nScanLineCount := 0 to Height - 1 do
    begin
      pscanLine32 := Scanline[nScanLineCount];
      pscanLine32_2 := TranspBitmap.Scanline[nScanLineCount];
      for nPixelCount := 0 to Width - 1 do
        with pscanLine32[nPixelCount] do
         begin
          // all picels with are not clFuchsia in the transparent bitmap
          if NOT ((pscanLine32_2[nPixelCount].rgbBlue=255) AND (pscanLine32_2[nPixelCount].rgbRed=255) AND (pscanLine32_2[nPixelCount].rgbGreen=0)  ) then
             begin
             rgbReserved := 255;
             end
          else
             begin
               rgbBlue := 0;
               rgbRed := 0;
               rgbGreen := 0;
             end;
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;



procedure TAForm.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);

var b1,b2,b3:TBitmap;
BF: TBlendFunction;
begin
  // Example how it opacity works:
  b1 := TBitmap.Create;
  b1.SetSize(20,20);
  b1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  b1.Canvas.Rectangle(0,0,20,20);
  Canvas.Draw(10,10,b1,$ff);  // Works
  Canvas.Draw(40,10,b1,$66);  // Works

  // I need it in combination with TransparentColor:
  b3 := TBitmap.Create;
  b3.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;

  b2 := TBitmap.Create;
  b2.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
  // next 3 lines are different from above
  b2.Transparent := true;
  b2.TransparentColor := clFuchsia;
  b2.Canvas.Brush.Color := clFuchsia;
  b2.SetSize(20,20);
  b2.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  b2.Canvas.Ellipse(0,0,20,20);

  Canvas.Draw(10,40,b2,$ff);  // Works (full opacity)

  b3.SetSize(20,20);
  SetBitmapAlpha(b3,0);
  b3.Canvas.Draw(0,0,b2,$66);
  AdaptBitmapAlpha(b3,b2);
  Canvas.Draw(40,40,b3,$66);

  b1.Free;
  b2.Free;
  b3.Free;
end;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but there is a problem with your solution: if your form is not white it doesn't work. there is no transparency. if i draw the circle on a (f.e. black) form it has white corners.

Comment: i added a picture to my question to show you what i mean.

Comment: @linluk thank you for the feedback, I had an error in `AdaptBitmapAlpha`

Answer (score 2):

thanks to bummi (accepted answer)!
i put his solution in a class helper. here is the code if anybody need it:

```
unit uBitmapHelper;

interface

uses
  Vcl.Graphics;

type
  TBitmapHelper = class Helper for TBitmap
  private
  type
    TRgbaRec = packed record
      r,g,b,a:Byte;
    end;
    PRgbaRec = ^TRgbaRec;
    PRgbaRecArray = ^TRgbaRecArray;
    TRgbaRecArray = array [0 .. 0] of TRgbaRec;
  public
    procedure TransparentMaskedDraw(ACanvas:TCanvas;AX:Integer;AY:Integer;AMask:TColor;AOpacity:Byte);
  end;

implementation

{ TBitmapHelper }

procedure TBitmapHelper.TransparentMaskedDraw(ACanvas:TCanvas;AX,AY:Integer;AMask:TColor;AOpacity:Byte);
var i,j:Integer;
    line1,line2:PRgbaRecArray;
    mask:PRgbaRec;
    tmp:TBitmap;
begin
  mask := @AMask;
  tmp := TBitmap.Create;
  tmp.SetSize(self.Width,self.Height);
  tmp.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
  tmp.HandleType := bmDIB;
  tmp.IgnorePalette := true;
  tmp.AlphaFormat := afDefined;
  for i := 0 to tmp.Height - 1 do begin
    line1 := tmp.Scanline[i];
    for j := 0 to tmp.Width - 1 do begin
      line1[j].a := 0;
    end;
  end;
  tmp.Canvas.Draw(0,0,self,AOpacity);
  for i := 0 to tmp.Height - 1 do begin
    line1 := tmp.ScanLine[i];
    line2 := self.ScanLine[i];
    for j := 0 to tmp.Width - 1 do begin
      if not((line2[j].r = mask.r) and (line2[j].g = mask.g) and (line2[j].b = mask.b)) then begin
        line1[j].a := $ff;
      end else begin
        line1[j].r := 0;
        line1[j].g := 0;
        line1[j].b := 0;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  ACanvas.Draw(AX,AY,tmp,AOpacity);
  tmp.Free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: neat :). I don't want to touch you code but IMHO your TRgbaRec should look like `TRgbaRec = packed record
      r,g,b,a:Byte;
    end;` using fuchsia it won't matter since red and blue are both 255, try it with clRed, you will find 255 in blue with your definition.

Comment: @bummi: thx, you helped me a lot with this topic. i have only tested it with clFuchsia :-S

Answer (score 1):

The oldest answer is fine, please find some easy reshuffle.
This example also shows how to put one png-image with opacity on another by respecting the transparency.

`procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
//define your own transparent color by setting RGB-values
const cTransR=255; cTransG=255; cTransB=255;
      clTrans= $10000*cTransB + $100*cTransG + cTransR;

var bmp1,bmp2:TBitmap;
    pngTemp: TPngImage;
    I:integer;

    procedure SetAlphaTransparent(VAR LBitmap:TBitmap);
    type   TRGBQuadArray = ARRAY [0..0] OF TRGBQuad;
    var    I, J: integer;
           LscanLine32:^TRGBQuadArray;
    begin
        // I found no other way than scanning pixel by pixel to recover default opacity
        for I := 0 to LBitmap.Height - 1 do begin
          LscanLine32:=LBitmap.ScanLine[I];
          for J := 0 to LBitmap.Width - 1 do
            with LscanLine32[J] do
              if NOT((rgbRed=cTransR)AND(rgbGreen=cTransG)AND(rgbBlue=cTransB)) then
                rgbReserved := 255; // make pixel visible, since transparent is default
        end;
    end;

    Procedure SetAlphaProperty(Var LBitmap:TBitmap; LWidth, LHeight:integer);
    begin
        // You will need a different format Bitmap to allow alpha values
        LBitmap.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
        LBitmap.HandleType  := bmDIB;
        LBitmap.alphaformat := afDefined;
        LBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clTrans;
        LBitmap.SetSize(LWidth,LHeight);
    end;

begin
  // create any background on your Form, by placing IMG:Timage on the From
  pngTemp := TPngImage.Create;
  pngTemp.LoadFromFile( GetCurrentDir()+'\figure1.png' );
  IMG.Canvas.Draw((IMG.Width-pngTemp.Width) div 2,  // fit png into the center
                  (IMG.Height-pngTemp.Height) div 2,pngTemp);
  pngTemp.Free;

  // First example how it opacity works with transparency
  bmp1 := TBitmap.Create;
  SetAlphaProperty(bmp1,35,35);
  // a circle has a surrouding area, to make transparent
  bmp1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  bmp1.Canvas.Ellipse(5,5,30,30);
  SetAlphaTransparent(bmp1);
  // show some circles with different opacity
  for I := 0 to 7 do
      IMG.Canvas.Draw(I*40-30,10,bmp1,(8-I)*32);
  bmp1.Free;

  // Another example using a different png-file
  bmp2 := TBitmap.Create;
  SetAlphaProperty(bmp2,Img.Width,Img.Height);
  // load a transparent png-file and put it into the alpha bitmap:
  pngTemp := TPngImage.Create;
  pngTemp.LoadFromFile( GetCurrentDir()+'\figure2.png' );
  pngTemp.Transparent := true;
  bmp2.Canvas.Draw((bmp2.Width-pngTemp.Width) div 2,// fit png into the center
                   (bmp2.Height-pngTemp.Height) div 2,pngTemp);
  pngTemp.Free;
  // draw the second image with transparancy and opacity onto the first one
  SetAlphaTransparent(bmp2);
  IMG.Canvas.Draw(0,0,bmp2,$66);
  bmp2.Free;
end;`